# My app painting over the iPhone status bar

Tags: iphone, statusbar, codenameone

Today I made my first version of my app to run on the iPhone.  When I did this I see that it paints over the area where the status bar is at the top of the screen, but that the status bar is also painted so that there is a mix of both.

I did try to set the hide status bar property of the build to true, but with the same result.

What I'd really like is that my app should retain the status bar and paint up to it but not where the status bar is.

How can i do this in Codenameone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 7 and newer expects your app to draw underneath the status bar, its a design choice by Apple and as a developer you are supposed to leave space for the status bar.

The default native theme on iOS has a `StatusBar` UIID style that pads the top but if you chose to remove the `includeNative` theme constant or remove that padding this won't work as expected.

Comment: So, If I use includeNative = false then I have to leave some space?  Is there any way to know how much space is needed?

Comment: Also, I use the Title feature of my theme to provide a header picture to all my screens (as per another stackoverflow question you answered to me).  If I need to put some space in there for the statusbar, is there any way to make the size of the title area larger so that I can accomodate both the picture and the space?

Comment: We leave 3mm which you can configure in the style or use the `Display.convertToPixels` method. I don't recall that question but generally you can just add an element above it that will have 0 size on non-iOS platforms and fill up the space the way you want to on iOS. Notice that we recommend using `includeNative=true` which hides issues like this...

Comment: OK, now I'm trying it with includeNative=true which seems to be OK.  But I still have one issue.  My style for the background of each screen has a background color.  The area above the title picture is painted white.  Can I make it transparent instead so that the iPhone status bar is painted on top of my background color?

Comment: Style the `TitleArea` UIID either by setting its border to empty, transparency to 0 or by setting its color.